# lync meeting url to be created using ucma and send via EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ucma

I am using EWS to create and send outlook meetings. 
But now i need to create a lync meeting and simply send the url to participants using EWS, so they can join in the same lync audio call. Sending mails via EWS part is done, but I am unable to generate the lync meeting url throuhg EWS but i can generate normal meeting. Some suggested UCMA and UCWA, but i have not found any supporting C# code that elaborate the process. I have found only theories even on microsoft site that also ambigious. If anyone know how to achieve this in C# server side, Thanks for the answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible using UCMA, I'm not sure about UCWA though.

For your requirement, you could probably wrap a WCF service around your UCMA application(C#), that talks to a Lync server to create ad-hoc conferences and return the meeting URL. The UCMA application can be hosted on a separate application server added to the Lync topology as an [application endpoint](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/01/ucma-endpoints-choosing-between-application-and-user-endpoints/).

I suggest reading [Tom's blog](http://www.thoughtstuff.co.uk/) or this [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=hQwFnlALbEIC&pg=PR1&dq=Professional+Unified+Communications+Development+with+Microsoft+Lync+Server+2010&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5ycy-0aHKAhXIj44KHdx-CpcQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=Professional%20Unified%20Communications%20Development%20with%20Microsoft%20Lync%20Server%202010&f=false), to get a better idea of UCMA's capabilities

Comment: thanks for the answer. but ucma is not feasible to be used as i have to merely generate a url. and I made some searches and found for web application UCWA is better option but it provides javascript library and i have to achieve my funcionality on serverside.